# How to create a paragraph in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, textview

I want to create a layout of the list item as shown in the image.I divided it into three parts taking whole layout as Linear(orientation-horizontal).Three parts are
1) Image
2) Paragraph
3) three edit text in a linear layout.
I have problem in the second part as the length of paragraph (Text View) it disturbs the next part.I also try by putting weight in relative layout but it does not work.What is the solution for this problem?
[How to do something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Hy7.png)
Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/hammer"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_icon"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="skvnksjdjbkjbkjb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_detail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_name"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="fkvjbfvkjbv"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="fkvjbfvkjbv"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="fkvjbfvkjbv"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `layout_weight`, the `layout_width` (for `horizontal` `LinearLayouts`) should be set to `0dp`